# How to make different bevelled image blocks as links?

Tags: html, css

I'm solving problem with something like responsive image map and don't know which solution is best.

I have this 
[desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3zA5.png)

and this 
[mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtaWV.png)

Whole image and text block with background must be link to page. Images and texts will be editing by users so I don't think that skew is best solution.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ check this out, but keep in mind browser support, e.g. clip-path not supported by Edge/IE

Comment: Thanks for recommendations, but we need support all standard browsers.

Answer (score 0):

using images for a responsive design is kind of weird, but I think the easiest way for you to do that is by using [imagemap](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/)

else you can imagine transparent divs placed over your image, or if the whole image is just a link, juste put it in an 'a' tag,

if you want your mobile and desktop version to link to 2 different pages, unse php $_SERVER or javascript to get, for example, the url or width of the screen depending on your way to change you design

Comment: Thanks for answer Neil.

Ok, Maybe I'm speaking inaccurately - by Images I don't think img tag. It includes background-image too.

Is imagemap responsive? I don't think so. Responsive way in our project is not just for 2 brekpoints(desktop, mobile). It will scale in desktop and mobile version too. So these blocks can't have static areas.

And how do you imagine rendering these transparent divs? It must not be just big rectangles. I need preserve shape.

I don't need 2 different links.

Comment: @KarolinaVolna sadly imagemap is not responsive, even if jquery addon can do that https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps, for transparent divs, you can, with css before after and transform make some cool shapes, but i agree it won't be a real fix... if only you had 6 image divs and a white background, it will be way easier.